# How to store Schedule using Node.js just like a calender

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-modules

I am new to node and have something to ask about. I am thinking of making a project in which a shop/doctor can show their available time slots and other people can book time slots for them. 
But What I am confused about is that how I get to store the time slots in the database?
I am going to use MongoDB for it and I want to store the data.  Like get data from the front end and store it in DB. And when someone go to their profile they can see their available time slots.

The Time slots would be fixed 1 hour (12:00 - 13:00) and so on.

How am I able to do that?

Any suggestions would be really appreciating.

Thank You